# Получить время выполнения функций

Tags: php, php5

Мне нужно получить время выполнения функций. Метод по типу microtime не подходит. Мне нужно вытянуть время выполнения всех функций на сайте. Например, при выводе ошибки мы видим это время в колонке time:
[image: img]
Можно как-то добраться до этого времени?

Answer (score 3):

Для таких вещей используются дополнительные расширения: XDebug, XHProf, APD и т.д.
У них есть или API или log-format, который можно парсить

Хорошо описано в:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943916/php-function-execution-time-for-debugging
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script